# Should an animation be placed in a runnable?

Tags: android, animation

In my application , i m applying an animation on layout. This animation put the layout off the screen and put it in from the other side :

```
private void slideAnimation(final int sens)
{

    Animation animOut = null;
    if(sens == -1) {
        animOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_out_left);
    } else {
        animOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }

    animOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Animation animIn = null;
            if(sens == -1) {
                animIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_in_right);
            } else {
                animIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_in_left);
            }
            camLayout.startAnimation(animIn);
        }
    });

    camLayout.startAnimation(animOut);
}
```

When needed i simply call slideAnimation().

It's working fine , but sometime we can see animation in a runnable. Should i consider using an other solution to slide out and in my layout or my code is OK ?

Thanks

Comment: Documentation states that when your animation triggers an update for animationListener, then your view is being redrawn, but it is unsure if this may cause some delays or may block app UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems ok to me! I gather you are just trying to schedule one animation to play after the another. And this code will do the job. I am not sure but i suppose the animation end listener does already listen from a different thread. So i don't think a new thread is required.

Answer (score 0):

IF this code is working as per your expectation then it's well and good. The problem with runnable is it will create on more process separately parallel to main thread and it will eat up main thread's memory and it will make your UI performance weak.